# CASE Statement error in SQLDEveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting an error in my case statement can someone please help

```
Case
When length(cat) < 3
Then SubStr(cat,1,1) || '0' || SubStr(cat,-1,1)
Else cat
End cat1,hd0,
Case
When GEMS_CMN_HD1_ABREV.hd1 <>"00"
then " / "
**else HD1_ABR,null**
end,
```

Seems like my error in Else hd1_ABR, NULL

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 18

Comment: A `CASE` statement can return only one value.  What do you expect the `CASE` statement to return if you get into the `ELSE` clause?  `HD1_ABR`?  `NULL`?  Something else?

Comment: corret, trying to create a field based on 4 headers, but get stuck

Comment: What is "correct"?  I asked multiple questions.  What do you mean by "headers" in your comment?  What do you expect the `CASE` statement to return if you get into the `ELSE` clause?

Comment: XX (HD0) / XX(HD1) / XXXXX (HD2) / XXXX(HD3)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help me much.  Is that supposed to be one column that contains a string that is made up of multiple components?  4 columns?  8 columns?  Something else?  How does that relate to the code that you posted?  How does that answer the question of what you want the `CASE` statement to return if you get into the `ELSE` clause?

Comment: It could be the double quotes - change them to single quotes. Also this looks weird with the comma inside the CASE: `**else HD1_ABR,null**` - is it supposed to be commented out?

Comment: You can only have one expression x or y in a `case boolexpr then x else y end` - so your `HD1_ABR,null` is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Replace " with ' and remove *. Put END before null. Use () for clarity and this is good practice also:

```
...(CASE When GEMS_CMN_HD1_ABREV.hd1 <>'00' then ' / ' else HD1_ABR end) As some_alias, null....
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you are trying to replace `NULL`, try `ISNULL`

```
Case
When length(cat) < 3
Then SubStr(cat,1,1) || '0' || SubStr(cat,-1,1)
Else cat
End cat1,hd0,
Case
When GEMS_CMN_HD1_ABREV.hd1 <>"00"
then " / "
else isnull(HD1_ABR,'')
end
```